# How to rotate ios simulator to landscape from the command line

Tags: ios-simulator

I am testing a flutter app on an iOS device in a CI/CD system from the commandline, so I am using `xcrun simctl` commands to controll the simulator.

For tablets, I want to test the app also when the device is in landscape mode. But I cannot find anything on how to rotate an ios simulator from the command line to lanscape.

Can I rotate the ios simulator to landscape using `xcrun simctl` or some other command line tool?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 1):

osascript -e 'tell application "Simulator" to activate' -e 'tell application "System Events" to click menu item "Rotate Right" of menu 1 of menu bar item "Device" of menu bar 1 of application process "Simulator"'